# StackExchange.Redis timeouts GET

Tags: stackexchange.redis

I am facing the issue with timeouts when using the StackExchange.Redis. Everything that I could find on stackoverflow I have tried.

Here is what I am getting: `Timeout performing GET XXX, inst: 4, mgr: ProcessReadQueue, err: never, queue: 9, qu: 0, qs: 9, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 65536, ar: 1, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=400,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=35,Free=32732,Min=400,Max=32767)`

In almost all exceptions that I get only `queue` and `qs` are changing and it had the value up to `11`.

I am using nuget version `1.0.488`. Application is hosted on IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012. On that machine we have 32gb of RAM and it is used from 30-50%. I have set the `maxmemory` to `16gb` and the `maxheap` to 22gb. Saving to disk is disabled. I am using it only as a session storage.

Redis server(version x64-2.8.2402) is installed on the same machine. Here is the url for the [redis-cli info](http://screencast.com/t/ZMhPTwI9Lwbo) that i have.

Also this is the part of exception that I am getting:

```
System.TimeoutException: Timeout performing GET Airports, inst: 1, mgr: ProcessReadQueue, err: never, queue: 4, qu: 0, qs: 4, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 65536, ar: 1, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=400,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=20,Free=32747,Min=400,Max=32767), clientName: OWNEROR-G875DJG   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1927    at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisBase.cs:line 80    at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.StringGet(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line 1451    at Resvoyage.Services.RedisCacheProvider.GetValue[T](String key) in c:\Development\thomalex\resvoyage\Resvoyage.Services\RedisCacheProvider.cs:line 88
```

This is how my connection string is looking `<add key="LocalRedis" value="127.0.0.1:6379,connectTimeout=25000,allowAdmin=true,password=xxx" />`. ConnectionTimeout was `15000` and i tried incresing it to `25000`

I have also increased `minIoThread` in `machine.config` for IIS. Here is the values that I have placed `<processModel autoConfig="true" minIoThreads="50" minWorkerThreads="50" maxWorkerThreads = "100" maxIoThreads = "100"/>`

Answer (score 4):

Read redis slowlog to see if there is any slow queries on redis. Maybe you are using keys command? Redis is single threaded so one slow query could block everything and as the client will not wait for redis forever you run into timeouts.

Comment: slowlog was showing me that i had some SETEX that were slow. I am not sure if that was directly causing the timeouts. I have data that is up to 7mb when doing save. Here is example what i get: 1) (integer) 3852
2) (integer) 1478858333
3) (integer) 19014

Comment: Writing 7MB blobs is a heavy operation that blocks the single thread. Any way to reduce the size?

Comment: No, not quite. I am storing data returned from 3rd party service and that size can vary.